# How to select Content of ALL div's with PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to select contents of every DIV tags in PHP.

Just imagine we have this HTML page :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="one">Content1</div>
        <span>blah..</span>
        <div class="two">Content2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now , i want to have every DIV tag content, For example from that HTML code , I want to have `Content1` in One variable and the `Content2` in the other Variable and so on ....
Just need to access the parts easily. Just this.

**Every page have random number of DIV tags, so i need a flexable Code to detect DIV tags and put the content of every one in array or any type of variable..**

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$divs = array();
$HTML = '<html>
    <body>
        <div class="one">Content1</div>
        <span>blah..</span>
        <div class="two">Content2</div>
    </body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($HTML);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div) {
   array_push($divs, $div->textContent);
}
var_dump($divs);
```

[example](https://eval.in/172155)

Comment: Thanks alot. And if i have a address , How to put URL of it ?

Comment: `$doc->loadHTML(file_get_conents($address));`

Answer (score 1):

try to use strip_tags() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

You can download **[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**

---

And access the `div` tags like this :

```
$html = file_get_html('urltopage.com');
foreach($html->find('div') as $e)
echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```